# How I can get access to my session variable, which was put from cross-domain ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have 2 domains:

```
panggoo.com

babbage.ru
```

The panggoo.com has a JS code

```
var xhr=pg_get_xhr();
var data=new FormData();
data.append('get_ads', 1);
data.append('count', count);
data.append('token', owner_token);
xhr.open('post', '//babbage.ru/php/external.php', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange=function () {
    ...
}
xhr.send(data);
```

The babbage.ru/php/external.php has a php follow below

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_start();
if (@$_POST['get_ads']) {
    $_SESSION['a']=1;
} else {
    echo $_SESSION['a'];
}
```

It works fine, but... I can't get a session variable from the opening the link babbage.ru/php/external.php;

I did check it from getting ajax, it's showing fine, but when I ask babbage.ru/external.php - `$_SESSION` is null

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: You can't get the session variable from another domain. What you can do is to make an ajax request to the domain and return the session variable.

Comment: If you work cross domain it'sb est to use a cooki..

Comment: So... I put a JS (it shows a some div) to another domain, and I need check - Did see user it before click?

Comment: @daan you should put that into an answer

Comment: @daan I need get a session from my own domain, which was put from another with ajax.